# Crawl depth for URLs added through metadata-and-url feed

Tags: google-search-appliance

We have a need to add specific URLs through metadata-and-url feed and prevent GSA to follow links found on these pages. URLs found on this pages must be ignored even if they specified in *Follow Patterns* rules.

Is it possible to specify crawl depth for URLs added through *metadata-and-url* feed or maybe there are some other ways to prevent GSA follow URLs found on specific pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve this problem with just a metadata-and-URL feed. The GSA is going to crawl the links that it finds, unless you can specify patterns to block them.

There are a couple possible solutions I can think of.

1. You could replace the metadata-and-URL feed with a content feed. You'd then have to fetch whatever you want to index and include that in the feed. Your fetch program could remove all of the links, or it could "break" relative links by specifying an incorrect URL for each of the documents. You'd then have to rewrite the incorrect URLs back to the correct URLs in your search result display page. I've done the second approach before, and that's pretty easy to do.
2. You could use a crawl proxy to block access to any of the links you don't want the GSA to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to prevent this is to add the following to the "HEAD" section of your HTML.

This will prevent the GSA (and any other search engine) from following any links on the page.

Comment: Hi Terry. Thanks for reply. We need specify this rules only for GSA, this pages must be reachable for other search engines.

Comment: The GSA is a web crawler so it is going to follow the links unless you are prepared to configure the GSA with a list of known URLs not to crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you can't add the relevant nofollow meta tags to your content then you can handle this using your follow and crawl patterns.

From the [official documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/url_patterns.html#1076663):

Google recommends crawling to the maximum depth, allowing the Google algorithm to present the user with the best search results. You can use URL patterns to control how many levels of subdirectories are included in the index.

For example, the following URL patterns cause the search appliance to crawl the top three subdirectories on the site www.mysite.com:

```
regexp:www\\.mysite\\.com/[^/]*$
regexp:www\\.mysite\\.com/[^/]*/[^/]*$
regexp:www\\.mysite\\.com/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*$
```

Comment: HI BigMikeW, thanks for your reply! The problem is that pages can contain other URLs with the same pattern(the same deep). E.g.We add URL http://example.com/123 through feed, crawler go to this page and find http://example.com/223 URL and add it to index, but only 123 must be added.

Comment: You can pass in robots nofollow in the same way you would pass in any other metadata in your feed.Have you tried adding the robots metadata to each document in your feed?

Comment: Yes, i tried. It looks like GSA ignores them. _Generally, robots META tags with a value of noindex, nofollow, or noarchive can be embedded in the head of an HTML document to prevent the search appliance from indexing links or following them in the document. However, robots META tags in a feed file are not honored, just the META tags in the HTML documents themselves._ https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html#1073150